# Setar Interval a cada 1 segundo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um problema: Para verificar se o botão está visível **(ele tem um tempo 30 minutos para aparecer. Mas como a função varia para remover ele, pode aumentar o tempo para ele aparecer por isso acho melhor usar Intervalo de 1 segundo)**, precisa setar um Intervalo de 1 segundo:

```
setInterval(function() {
if ($('#botão').is(':visible')){
FUNÇÃO "X"

}
}, 1000)
```

Assim que o botão estivesse **visível** iniciasse uma **função "X"** que retirasse o botão em um tempo de 15 a 20 segundos **Obs: pode variar** e só executaria uma vez essa função.**E talvez a função "X não consegue remover o botão, ai cancela o intervalo ou manda um alert dizendo que não foi removido o botão**".

**Porém se eu seto o intervalo de 1 segundo, ele fica executando a função "X" toda hora, pois o botão está visível nesse tempo de 15 a 20 segundos que a função "X" tenta retirar o botão**

Como posso fazer para que não ficasse executando toda hora a função "X" e fizesse por exemplo:

Se a **função "X"** estiver sendo executada, o **intervalo de 1 segundo** para. E se a função não retirar o botão, ai cancela o intervalo ou manda um alert dizendo que não foi retirado o botão ou faz o intervalo voltar. **Se puderem me dizer como fica essas 3 funções agradeço muito.**

Alguém tem idéia de como posso fazer isso? Valeu

Comment: Me parece que você deveria usar o `setTimeout()` ao invés do `setInterval()`. Explique melhor o seu problema e inclua o código a sua pergunta.

Comment: Mas o botão aparece em um intervalo de tempo de 30 minutos, esqueci de mencionar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie o seu setInterval e salve numa variável, depois quando for para executar a função você remove o intervalo pela variável criada.

Exemplo:

```
var verificar;
function iniciarVerificacao(){
    if(verificar) clearInterval(verificar); // Isso evita que o intervalo rode mais de uma vez.
    verificar=setInterval(function() {
        if ($('#botão').is(':visible')){
            clearInterval(verificar);
            FUNÇÃO "X"
        }
    }, 1000);
}
iniciarVerificacao(); // Chame quando desejar reiniciar.
```

Comment: Ok, e como faz para retornar o intervalo caso a função X não remove o botão? Pois o intervalo é cancelado no clearInterval(verificar) né? Ou continua no intervalo de 1 segundo?

Comment: Você pode definir o intervalo em uma função. Executar a função assim que o script iniciar e caso deseje reiniciar chamar a função novamente. Como editei agora na minha resposta.

Comment: Mas se eu quiser reiniciar usando: iniciarVerificacao(); dentro da função, vai reiniciar?

Comment: sim, contanto que a função iniciarVerificacao() estiver dentro do mesmo script ou puder ser acessada globalmente por outros arquivos js. (Funções dentro da chamada do jQuery "$(function(){ **seu código** });" não podem ser chamadas de fora dela)