# Repetir intervalo

Tags: javascript

Olá, eu fiz um post perguntando isso: [Setar Interval a cada 1 segundo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303646/setar-interval-a-cada-1-segundo)

E tenho o seguinte código:

```
iniciarVerificacao();
var verificar;
function iniciarVerificacao(){
   if(verificar) clearInterval(verificar); 
   verificar=setInterval(function() {
      if ($('#botao').is(':visible')){
         console.log('botão vísivel');
         clearInterval(verificar);
         $('#botao').trigger('click');
         console.log('botão removido');
         iniciarVerificacao();
      }else{
         console.log('botão não vísivel');
         iniciarVerificacao(); << Aqui seria para reiniciar e verificar novamente se o botão está vísivel (function iniciarVerificacao()
      }
   }, 1000);
}
```

Oque eu queria: Que, ele verificasse a cada 1 segundo se o botão está vísivel na página (depois de uma hora **(ou varia, por isso o intervalo de 1 segundo)** a página atualiza e o botão aparece), e quando aparecer, ele clica no botão, e aparece uma hora de tempo para aparecer novamente, e começa de novo a verificação. E ficar nesse ciclo infinito, porém o intervalo para quando estiver removendo o botão, resumindo:

```
1->Verifica se o botão está ativo
2->**Para o intervalo para remover o botão**
3->Ativa o intervalo novamente para ver se o botão está ativo (dentro de uma hora)
```

Mas estou com alguns problemas, quando o botão aparece o script fica parado, não sei se fica parado porque a página **atualiza**, ou se ele fica parado no **else**, pois se deixar rodando o script eternamente, ele fica parado na mensagem: console.log('botão não vísivel');

Alguém sabe oque pode ser?

Comment: Vc está usando dois ids diferentes: `#botão` e `#button`, é isso mesmo? São dois botões distintos?

Comment: Adicione um parâmetro na função que servirá para indicar o tempo. Ex: `function iniciarVerificacao(ms)` e você pode utilizar `}, ms);` ao invés de `}, 1000);`. E quando for chamar a função `iniciarVerificacao(1000);` para verificar a cada segundo ou `iniciarVerificacao(3600000);` para verificação a cada hora.

Comment: Editei o post, coloquei errado, os dois são botao. Valdeir, esse código verifica, porém quando atualiza a página o script para, ou ele para no else, não sei qual dos dois.

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa de tantos `clearInterval(verificar)`. Basta que o `iniciarVerificacao()` nunca seja chamado, ou seja chamado com atraso,

```
var verificar;
(function iniciarVerificacao() {
    verificar = setTimeout(function () {
        var verificar2;

        if ($('#button').is(':visible') {
            console.log('botão visível');
            $('#button').trigger('click');
            console.log('botão removido');
        } else {
            console.log('botão não visível');
        }

        verificar2 = setTimeout(function () {
            iniciarVerificacao();
        }, 500);
    }, 500);
})();
```

Veja também se o botão já não está apagado por *default*.

Se quer controlar quando o fluxo percorrerá todo o `iniciarVerificacao` ou não, coloque um desvio de fluxo,

```
var devoDesviar = false;
var verificar;
(function iniciarVerificacao() {
    verificar = setTimeout(function () {
        var verificar2;

        if (!devoDesviar) { // condição para desvio de fluxo
            if ($('#button').is(':visible') {
                console.log('botão visível');
                $('#button').trigger('click');
                console.log('botão removido');
            } else {
                console.log('botão não visível');
            }
        }

        verificar2 = setTimeout(function () {
            iniciarVerificacao();
        }, 500);
    }, 500);
})();

(function desvio() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        devoDesviar = !devoDesviar;
        desvio();
    }, 30000); // a cada 30 segundos, chaveio a verificação do botão button.
})();
```

EDIT: no caso de a página estar sendo cacheada, tente colocar as seguintes tags nela,

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"></meta>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"></meta>
```

Comment: Como faço para que continue funcionando mesmo que a página atualize?

Comment: Por que a página iria atualizar?

Comment: A página atualiza automaticamente para o botão aparecer

Comment: Mas o código deveria funcionar independentemente se a página atualiza ou não

Comment: Talvez o botão esteja desativado após atualizar a página? Ou a página fica cacheada, talvez?

Comment: O botão fica desativado quando é clicado, ai aparece um tempo de 1 hora e quando termina, a página atualiza e o botão fica ativado. Uma pergunta, para chamar a função para começar o processo de verificação preciso colocar o: iniciarVerificacao()? Pois se não a função não vai iniciar nunca?

Comment: Se você usar do jeito que eu fiz, `(function iniciarVerificacao() { ... })();`, não precisa chamá-la. Mas tem que se certificar que esse código está dentro de um `$(document).ready()` ou `window.onload`

Comment: Esse desvio que você disse, se eu colocar ele, depois que o botão estiver vísivel, vai dar um timeout de 30 segundos para esperar o botão ser removido e depois a função iniciarVerificacao irá iniciar novamente?

Comment: Foi só um exemplo, @Slinidy. Pode seguir a lógica para suas necessidades.

Comment: É que o foco da pergunta é essa, eu colocar um timeout para não ficar tentando remover o botão toda hora

Comment: Experimenta rodar o código com esse exemplo, pra ver se funciona da forma que você quer. Troque o `30000` por um outro valor, para variar o caso.